# how to add new array into my jsonArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json var, and I want to add new array into it.

I would like to get:

```
myJson = {
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2",
   "newArray":[
       {"array1": "valueArray1"},
       {"array2":"valueArray2"}
   ]
}

var newArray = [{"array1": "valueArray1"},{"array2":"valueArray2"}];
```

```js
var myJson = {
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2"
}

var newArray = [{"array1": "valueArray1"},{"array2":"valueArray2"}];


myJson.push(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it return an error:

```
uncaught TypeError: myJson.push is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:8
```

why is it incorrect?

Comment: myJson is not a jsonArray, its an object

Comment: please use different names for non [JSON](http://json.org/) objects. your variable with the name *`myJson`* is not an array.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin it's an object - nothing to do with JSON. JSON is just a method of encoding a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's set properties instead, because your myJson is object not Array

```js
var myJson = {
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2"
}

var newArray = [{"array1": "valueArray1"},{"array2":"valueArray2"}];


myJson.newArray = newArray;
console.log(myJson);
```